# AndroidManifest.xml syntax check tool?

Tags: android, xml, validation, android-manifest

Is there any standalone ( separate from Eclipse or IDE specific ) tool that can check an `AndroidManifest.xml` file for errors?

I had an annoying problem recently where I typed `reciever` when it should have been `receiver` ( *i* before *e* except after *c*...). Nothing to indicate the error other than a failure on run time.

Comment: to avoid that kind of problems , use AutoCompletion Code in eclipse , type `<r` and then the command of autocompletion code in eclipse ( Ctrl+Space in windows ) , and then choose `receiver`.
other thing , what version if ADT are you using ?

Comment: @Houcine I'm sorry I should have been more clear in my question. I don't use Eclipse that's why I mentioned 'standalone'. I use vim and compile via Ant typically.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see it , but i think that eclipse is the best free IDE for developing JAVA Android :), if you working on Linux OS , there is a version for eclipse to work with. otherwise , i hope someone gives you more informations about a 'standalone tool' for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android's Lint is available [from the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html). Whether it catches that specific error, I can't say.

Comment: This does look like the kind of tool I'm looking for, it doesn't seem to catch the specific error I mentioned but perhaps there is some configuration I can do.

Comment: @jmathew: Eventually, writing your own Lint rules will be formally supported. I think there are some docs floating around http://tools.android.com of how to do it today, though you may need to tweak them over time until the API stabilizes.

Answer (score 1):

Well Eclipse doesn't really support XML editing out of the box, and Android doesn't have a syntax checker for XML files. I guess they expect people to use the UI builder.

You'll need to install a third party plugin, none of which, I believe, are specifically catered to aid in Android XML files.

Answer (score -1):

public ArrayList parseJSON(String result) 
{

ArrayList users = new ArrayList();
        try {

```
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(json_data.getString("name"));
            user.setPlace(json_data.getString("place"));
            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return users;
}
```

Comment: i am getting error <users> and parseJSON in line 1 & 2

Comment: This appears to be it's own question. I recommend you delete this and ask it separately by clicking 'Ask Question'. See this link for how best to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask